# How to get lodash from window?

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-typings

In pure JS I had code

`const { _ } = window;`

Now I migrating project to Typescript 2.8 and it causing error:

> Error TS2459: Type 'Window' has no property '_' and no string index signature.

tsconfig:

```
{
  'allowJs': true,
  'allowSyntheticDefaultImports': true,
  "target": "es2017",
  "baseUrl": "src",
  'resolveJsonModule': true,
  'noImplicitAny': false
}
```

PS: I cannot use lodash through import in code.

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be `const _ = (window as any)._ as _;` but I'm not sure if that's the "best"/"cleanest" way.

Comment: @AndyJ At least it worked. Now I have error "Error TS2686: '_' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead."

Comment: try using  `const _  = window["_"];`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Tested first of all - does not work

Answer (score 2):

To have lodash as '_' on the window using typescript, you probably want to do something like this:

```
import {LoDashStatic} from 'lodash'   // import the library
declare let window: {                 // declare the type for window
  _: LoDashStatic;                    // (we'd add jquery like so too)
}     
const {_} = window;                   // create the convenient constant

_.range(1, 3);                         // works now w/o compile error
```